# ImageViews on Homescreen Widget slow the Homescreen performance

Tags: android, memory-management, android-widget, imageview, homescreen

I have a problem that I cannot find any documentation/ solutions on the web. 
I have an application with a home screen widget that displays a few imageviews, the number of imageviews is not final, it can be changed by the user (from inside the app) and by the app itself automatically. When reaching over 6-8 imageviews the homescreen starts to get laggy ( dragging app icons, resizing widgets, moving between screens).
Imageviews are populated from a uri.

the imageviews are set this way :

```
remoteViews.setImageViewUri(R.id.imageView1,uri1));
```

The widget layout is a regular linear layout with wighted imageviews

Any information on this issue will be great

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by resizing the images, making them smaller.